# Sorbet not picking up obvious mismatch of Hash signature

Tags: ruby, sorbet

Given the following code:

```
# typed: strict

extend T::Sig

sig { params(x: T::Hash[String,String]).returns(NilClass) }
def foo(x); end

foo("foo" => 123)
```

[Playground Link](https://sorbet.run/#%23%20typed%3A%20strict%0A%0Aextend%20T%3A%3ASig%0A%0Asig%20%7B%20params(x%3A%20T%3A%3AHash%5BString%2CString%5D).returns(NilClass)%20%7D%0Adef%20foo(x)%3B%20end%0A%0Afoo(%22foo%22%20%3D%3E%20123)%0A)

I would expect Sorbet to recognize that the passed hash has the wrong value parameter. How can I properly declare a signature which will ensure the hash passed only contains allowed values types?

Comment: This may not be the most polite opinion but no one should be wasting time using sorbet.

Comment: @anothermh is that due to Sorbet specifically or resistance to typing in ruby in general?

Comment: In addition to being a solution in search of a problem it's the wrong solution for the problem it purports to solve. It's unnecessary complexity. It's unnecessary performance overhead. It's yet another DSL. If someone believes they truly need it then they shouldn't be using Ruby. The list goes on and on. It isn't just unnecessary; it actively wastes time and resources. If Stripe wants to throw money away on a silly and buggy vanity project then good for them, but I would never pay a developer to waste time making something slower and more complex that is harder for others to adopt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a known issue in Sorbet

https://github.com/sorbet/sorbet/issues/713

You're doing everything right, and Sorbet let you down. Feel free to follow the issue, but we estimate that this particular bug will be quite hard to fix, because of some other constraints we're trying to maintain.